# how can I create Interface for a single variable and not a object

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-generics

I want to achieve something like this but don't want to type **'day' | 'week'** everytime:

```
const date: 'day' | 'week' = 'day'
```

but I'm unable to do something like this using **interfaces** in TypeScript

Comment: `type DateType = 'day' | 'week';`?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)

> A union type is a type formed from two or more other types, representing values that may be any one of those types

```
type DateType = 'day' | 'week';
const date: DateType = 'day';
```